# \pgfkeyscurrentkey is empty when it is supposed to expand to a key

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

Consider the following LaTeX manuscript, whose body, including comments, was copy-and-pasted from p. 883 of the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}
    % Define a test key and error handlers:
    \pgfkeys{/the/key/.code={Initial definition. }}
    \pgfkeys{/handlers/.unknown/.code={Unknown key '\pgfkeyscurrentkey'. }}
    % calling the test key yields ’Initial definition. ’:
    \pgfkeys{/the/key}
    % Change configuration:
    \pgfkeys{/handler config=only existing}
    % allowed: key *re*-definition:
    \pgfkeys{/the/key/.code={Re-Definition. }}
    % calling the key yields ’Re-Definition. ’:
    \pgfkeys{/the/key}
    % not allowed: definition of new keys:
    % this checks for ’/the/other key/.unknown’
    % and ’/handlers/.unknown’
    % and yields finally
    % ’Unknown key ‘/the/other key/.code‘’
    \pgfkeys{/the/other key/.code={New definition. }}
\end{document}
```

The comments (copied from the manual) indicate that the typeset text should be

> Initial definition. Re-Definition. Unknown key ‘/the/other key/.code‘

However, the actual typeset text is

> Initial definition. Re-Definition. Unknown key ''.

(Even the manual lists this as the actual typeset text!...)

Why doesn't the typeset text end with ‘/the/other key/.code‘, as the last comment (rightly) says it should?

Comment: Isn't that what you'd expect? There's no current key. Not sure what the manual means ....

Comment: @cfr: "always the macro `\pgfkeyscurrentkey` will have been set up to expand to the text of the *〈key〉* that is currently being
processed." (bottom of p. 880) The key that is being processed in the last line of `pgfkeys` code I listed in my post is `/the/other key/.code`.

Comment: This is probably related to a long-waiting-bug that keys don't expand timely as they used to be in version before 3.0.1a. Here `\pgfkeyscurrentkey` should have been expanded but does not. The ticket is on the bugtracker

Comment: @percusse: The same example with the same comments and the same wrong output appears all the way back (and including) the manual for version 2.10. But is it your opinion that it is a bug? cfr thinks otherwise.

Comment: @EvanAad Emphasis on *probably* and the bug is meant for v3 only.

Comment: @percusse: I've opened a bug ticket (my first ever for an open source project).